# Using background.js variables in chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

With `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, how can I use a variable from background.js in the inserted content script? I mean something like this:

```
(...)
var identificador = target.selectionText;
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                       {code:"alert(identificador);"});
(...)
```

That is just a example invented about I need to do. In my extension, my goal is set a variable with a portion of text selected (using context menus) and when the web is reloaded, search it in the document and if found a match, alert me. The only way that I know to do this is using regex and `document.body.innerText`, but I believe that I only can use `document.body.innerText` injecting JS with `executeScript`. So... exists any better way to do it? And if not, how I can send my variable with the text portion to the code executed by `executeScript`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to pass information from your background page (background.js) to the web page that is being viewed is by using a combination of [Content Scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

The Content Script allows you to add a JS file to the web page. This will be used to receive messages from the background.js and take action on the web page DOM.

The Message Passing gives you a mechanism to communicate, by passing a JSON object, between the background page and web page.

### Example of adding a Content Script:

```
{
    "name": "My extension",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }]
}
```

### Example contents of `background.js`:

```
// Get the current tab and send a message from it:
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
        identificador: target.selectionText
    });
});
```

### Example contents of `myscript.js`:

```
// Listen to the message
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request.identificador);      
});
```

Please note, Google now recommends that you use [Event Pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) instead of [Background Pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html).

Comment: Just thought I would point out that `chrome.tabs.getSelected` has been depreciated since chrome 16. use [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) instead.